# Can't record voice in Whatsapp

Tags: custom-roms, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-duos, voice-recording

I'm using s5 duos and I'm on a custom rom for sometime now and I just noticed something wrong that the voice icon is partially hidden and I can't access it.
I have attached a screen shot.
Is there any way to acess the voice icon?

[image: voice icon partially hidden]

<sup>Screenshot (Click to enlarge image)</sup>

Comment: What happens if you rotate your screen to landscape?

Comment: Still looks the same even in landscape mode @SuperThomasLab

Comment: Have yoyu already rebooted your device? What ROM are you using? If you are using CyanogenMod then apply the default theme... Please give more information.

Comment: I'm on GERIS rom that I downloaded from XDA. I tried rebooting and even reinstalled whatsapp and its still the same :(

Comment: OK, you should reinstall whatsapp. First make a backup of your messages in whatsapp settings and then uninstall, reinstall whatsapp from the playstore .

Comment: Already tried that @SuperThomasLab

Comment: And you didn't had any problems before installing the custom ROM? If so please disable Xposed etc. And have you set a custom DPI?

Comment: Well I actually didn't notice that, but i think it was working fine since my friend who have a single sim variant of the same mobile can use voice recording... no i hqve not set a custom DPI... I'll return shortly after disabling xposed and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you any further. I never had problems like this.

Comment: Thankyou @SuperThomasLab i see that a xposed module was actually causing the problem.. disabled it and now it works fine :)

Comment: I added an answer:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reboot your device. Try to reinstall Whatsapp. Disable any mods like custom DPI, custom theme, Xposed, etc...

Hope my answer helps you!